# Stack Exchange in regard of skill, time, material things (possibility to practicing certain other mertiouse deeds) wished/possible?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Atma wonders if there would be the possible and wish to make the practice of things like dana (gerneosity in regard of material things) or Veyyāvaca (serving others with time skill and effort) possible within Buddhism SE.

Maybe it could be done by a certain tag or even a sub-SE like meta.

Possible examples:

- How could take care of my cat (I try to join a retreat in May)?
- Can somebody help be to convert Dhamma texts into pdf for my website?
- We are planing to erect a Kuti. Do you like to join in this deed?

It would be also a matter in regard of deeds like inviting others to join ones merits by telling about them and therefor giving the chance to rejoice with them.

Atma is not sure if such would be now wished and welcome, since stack exchange seems to be limited on stacks in regard of mainly third part knowledge and knowledge as far as seen.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the proposal Bhante.

I think the Stack Exchange Format is not suited for such requests. This is an expert-forum based on the formular of *"best-answer"* possible. Diverting too much from this format could harm it or subtract from it.

This is my opinion on the topic as a moderator. I'm looking forward to see others opinion on it.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Mr/Mrs Lanka. Why should such harm having the "best answer"? Its btw not really meant as an porposal, its just a suggestion since Atma guesses that Dhamma practice is the most prior intention of this undertaking and nothing better to learn by actually doing.